# How to determine models of the world based upon the following knowledge base.

Tags: logic

I'm given the following knowledge base:

If a widget is sweet, then it is fattening, but if it is not sweet, then it is a non‐fattening salad. If a widget is either fattening or a salad then it is chocolate. A widget is good for you if it is chocolate.

How would I determine models of  the world based on that? I decided to break down the statements to the following.

> - “If a widget is sweet, then it is fattening”
>
>   $A\rightarrow B$
> - “If a widget is not sweet, then it is a non-fattening salad.”
>
>   $¬A \rightarrow (¬B ∨ C)$
> - “If a widget is either fattening or a salad then it is chocolate.”
>
>   $(B ∨ C) \rightarrow D$
> - “A widget is good for you if it is chocolate” ≡ “If a widget is chocolate, then it is good for you”
>
>   $D \rightarrow E$

Is my logic sound? I'm not sure whether "If a widget is sweet, then it is fattening, but if it is not sweet, then it is a non‐fattening salad" could be separated or if I need  to join them with an AND

From there would I need to just make a truth table to describe the  models?

Comment: Shouldn't your second expression be $$\neg A\to(\neg B\land C)?$$

Comment: @bof yes, you're totally right. i corrected it. ty

Comment: It still looks wrong to me. It looks like you're saying "if a widget is not sweet, then it is fattening or it's not a salad."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not mention the requirements for your knowledge base, but one would often use *first-order Horn clauses* here. The class of first-order Horn clauses is the sublanguage of first-order logic consisting of formulas that are either of the form

$$P_1(\vec{x_1}) \wedge \ldots P_k(\vec{x_k}) \Rightarrow C(\vec{x})$$

for $k \geq 1$ or of the form

$$P_1(\vec{x_1}) \wedge \ldots P_k(\vec{x_k})$$

for $k \geq 1$. In both cases, the $P_i$ are first-order predicates and we have that $\vec{x} \subseteq \vec{x_1} \cup \ldots \vec{x_k}$. The latter kind of clauses that do not use implication can be thought of as facts, the former can be thought of as rules.

First-order Horn clauses make it possible to use the satisfiability algorithm called *resolution*. The programming language Prolog is based on this idea.

To set up your model, first find out that the first-order predicates should be. In your case, they would be $Q(w)$, meaning that $Q$ holds for $w$, where $w$ is a widget.

For instance, you should have the predicates

- $F(w)$: $w$ is fattening
- $C(w)$: $w$ is chocolate
- $S(w)$: $w$ is salad

You can then write

*If a widget is either fattening or a salad then it is chocolate.*

as the collection of first-order Horn clauses

$$\{  F(w) \Rightarrow C(w),  S(w) \Rightarrow C(w) \}$$